OpenCV Template Matching - OpenCL with external gpu is slower than cpu rendering
I'm trying to find the fastest way to match templates.
I was surprised to see OpenCL being so much slower than CPU and CUDA rendering.
Normally I would go with CUDA, but I'm waiting for a new AMD GPU card so I have to use OpenCL.
Latest Timing Results:



Stage
Duration (in ms)




CPU
293.00


GPU
268.00


GPU OpenCL
539.00



Did I forget something or is OpenCL not optimized for my current Nvidia Quadro K620?
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("path-to-source-img");
std::vector<cv::Mat> templates;
std::vector<std::string> templatePaths = {"path/template1","path/template2"};
cv::Mat template_img = cv::imread("path/template1");

void loadTemplates() {
    for (const auto& path : templatePaths) {
        templates.push_back(cv::imread(path));
    }
}

void cpu() {
    START_TIMER
    cv::Mat imgCopy = img.clone();
    std::vector<std::future<cv::Point>> futures;

    auto matchTemplate = [](const cv::Mat& img, const cv::Mat& templ) {
        cv::Mat result;
        cv::matchTemplate(img, templ, result, cv::TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
        cv::Point maxLocPoint;
        cv::minMaxLoc(result, 0, 0, 0, &maxLocPoint);
        return maxLocPoint;
    };

    // Create a future for each template
    for (const auto& templ : templates) {
        futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, matchTemplate, img, templ));
    }

    // Collect results and draw rectangles
    for (size_t i = 0; i < templates.size(); ++i) {
        cv::Point maxLocPoint = futures[i].get();
        cv::Scalar color(0, 255 * (i + 1) / templates.size(), 255 * (templates.size() - i) / templates.size());
        cv::rectangle(imgCopy, cv::Rect(maxLocPoint, cv::Point(maxLocPoint.x + templates[i].cols, maxLocPoint.y + templates[i].rows)), color, 2);
    }

    END_TIMER(cpuMatching)
    cv::imshow("Result CPU Optimized", imgCopy);
    cv::waitKey(0);
}

void gpu() {
    START_TIMER
    cv::cuda::GpuMat srcGpu(img);
    std::vector<cv::cuda::GpuMat> templatesGpu;
    std::vector<cv::cuda::GpuMat> resultsGpu(templates.size());
    std::vector<cv::cuda::Stream> streams(templates.size());

    cv::Ptr<cv::cuda::TemplateMatching> matcher = cv::cuda::createTemplateMatching(img.type(), cv::TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);

    // Upload templates to GPU and launch matching operations
    for (size_t i = 0; i < templates.size(); ++i) {
        templatesGpu.emplace_back(templates[i]);
        matcher->match(srcGpu, templatesGpu.back(), resultsGpu[i], streams[i]);
    }

    // Process results
    std::vector<cv::Point> maxLocPoints(templates.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < templates.size(); ++i) {
        cv::Mat result;
        resultsGpu[i].download(result, streams[i]);

        streams[i].waitForCompletion();
        cv::minMaxLoc(result, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, &maxLocPoints[i]);
    }

    END_TIMER(gpuMatching)

    cv::Mat imgCopy = img.clone();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < templates.size(); ++i) {
        cv::Scalar color(0, 255 * (i + 1) / templates.size(), 255 * (templates.size() - i) / templates.size());
        cv::rectangle(imgCopy, cv::Rect(maxLocPoints[i], templates[i].size()), color, 2);
    }

    cv::imshow("Result GPU Stream Optimized", imgCopy);
    cv::waitKey(0);
}

// Not yet implemented to work with several templates like cpu and cuda
void gpuOpenCL() {
    START_TIMER
    // Enable OpenCL
   cv::ocl::setUseOpenCL(true);

    if (!cv::ocl::haveOpenCL()) {
        std::cout << "OpenCL is not available..." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // Get OpenCL device information
    cv::ocl::Context context;
    if (!context.create(cv::ocl::Device::TYPE_GPU)) {
        std::cout << "Failed creating the context..." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // Print the detected OpenCL devices
    std::cout << context.ndevices() << " GPU devices are detected." << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < context.ndevices(); i++) {
        cv::ocl::Device device = context.device(i);
        std::cout << "Device " << i << ": " << device.name() << std::endl;
    }

    cv::ocl::Device(context.device(0));

    cv::UMat result;
    result.create(img.rows - template_img.rows + 1, img.cols - template_img.cols + 1, CV_32FC1);

    cv::matchTemplate(img, template_img, result, cv::TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
    END_TIMER(gpuOpenCLMatching)

    double minVal, maxVal;
    cv::Point minLoc, maxLoc;
    cv::minMaxLoc(result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc);

    cv::rectangle(img, maxLoc, cv::Point(maxLoc.x + template_img.cols, maxLoc.y + template_img.rows), cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);

    cv::imshow("OpencCL GPU Result", img);
    cv::waitKey(0);
}

int main() {
    loadTemplates();
    cpu();
    gpu();
    gpuOpenCL();
    displayTimingStats();
    return 0;
}


My Quadro K420 had serious problems with OpenCL after new drivers. Perhaps same with your K620. Both are Kepler. Try old drivers (that support the same OpenCL version).

I think your benchmark is not setup properly.
Looking at your gpuOpenCL, it seems that START_TIMER / END_TIMER also surround device selection and creation code.
Anecdotally, this can be quite slow, and it doesn't seem like something you should include in your timings, since setting up the device is only needed once for multiple templates.
Similarly, you're also measuring the CPU <-> GPU latency in both of your non-CPU tests, which may not be relevant and adds some latency (except maybe if you're on an unified architecture).
Your cpu function also includes more code in the benchmark, which probably also affects timings.
It's hard to say for sure, but I think this probably explains the unexpected timings you're measuring.
